# She's hoping that she won't be away too long

Tags: sentence-meaning

> She(A) is hoping that she(B) won't be away too long.

A is the same person as B or A is different from B?

Comment: Both are possible, and neither is more likely in this fragment without context.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Very clear!

Answer (score 3):

Let’s use “hopes” rather than “is hoping”; in almost all circumstances that term would be more correct.

The word “she” is a pronoun and its meaning can only be known through context. Consequently, your sentence might carry either meaning.  Nonetheless, using the same pronoun to indicate two distinct people is confusing and stylistically clumsy: when the subject and object are different it is better to use a name or other identifier for at least one of them.

For example, suppose we had the text

> “Jane sees Emma driving away. She hopes that she won’t be away too long.”

It’s clear that Jane is the subject and Emna the object, but it would be better to use at least one of the names twice, or  an alternative identifier like “her friend”. E.g.,

> “Jane sees Emma driving away. She hopes her friend won’t be away too long.”

On the other hand, if the subject and object are the same person then this often isn’t necessary. Suppose our text were

> “Jane drives away from Emma. She hopes that she won’t be away too long.”

It’s clear that Jane is both the subject and object. Repeating the pronoun causes no confusion here, and it’s stylistically superior (because it’s less repetitive) to  using Jane’s name twice.